# How to apply ANOVA for multiple treatments over multiple days?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, repeated-measures

I have a dataset that contains ten different treatments (a1, a2, a3 etc.) applied to a substrate and the effect of that treatment is measured at six separate time points(1-6). There are four samples of substrate that are measured for each treatment at each time point.

Something like:

| Treatment | Time | Metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1. | 1. | 2.13 |
| a1. | 1. | 2.09. |
| a1. | 1. | 2.11. |
| a1. | 1. | 2.10. |
| a2. | 1. | 3.31 |
| a2. | 1. | 3.19. |
| a2. | 1. | 3.11. |
| a2. | 1. | 4.15. |
| ..... | .... | ... |
| a1. | 2. | 2.33 |
| a1. | 2. | 2.49. |
| a1. | 2. | 2.51. |
| a1. | 2. | 2.60. |
| a2. | 2. | 3.11 |
| a2. | 2. | 3.89. |
| a2. | 2. | 3.95. |
| etc. | etc. | etc. |

So, it seems that I can use ANOVA to compare the treatments to one another at EACH time point based on the different values of the metric for each treatment, but is there a way that I can compare all treatments to each other across all time points? Is there any special name for the multi-category/multi-timepoint ANOVA type test?

Additionally, how do I determine if my data is sufficiently "normal" to apply these methods? Clearly there's not enough data for each treatment and time point, and mixing treatments and/or time points isn't meaningful. Are these tests only applicable on larger data sets?

Comment: This is a repeated measures design, I added the tag. You can look through highky upvoted posts in that tag!

Comment: Have you recorded the data such that you can identify the individual substrate at each time ?